# Mature migratordotnet alternative

Tags: c#, migration, migratordotnet

I'm looking for a database migration framework (supporting most used database engine) for c# like migratordotnet that I'm actually use.

Is this the only "mature" choice?

**update**

I've found also:

- [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki)

Comment: What problems do you have with migratordotnet that you hope other frameworks might solve?

Comment: I don't know! I started using migratordotnet but I'm guessing if my choice was good or I should take another framework!

Comment: Personally, I'm pleased with it, and my company uses it for several projects. But as I haven't used any other frameworks, I cannot say how it compares to others. I've heard good (but vague) things about [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), but it is not free.

Comment: We have had success with FluentMigrator to manage schema for EF 4.1 code first at my organization.